# SQLLite : Groupby

Tags: sqlite

I have these 2 rows in my database and I want to subtract 2 different values from the same column and display the resut.

```
('^NSEI', '2021-09-03', 'Enter Long', 'Buy', 17284.59, '2023-08-30 15:22:51.857293')
('^NSEI', '2021-09-20', 'Exit Long', 'Sell', 17456.33, '2023-08-30 15:22:51.891464')
```

In the above case the sell value [17456.33] should be subtracted with the buy value [17284.59] and the result need to be displayed.

I tried Grouping By method, but couldn't achieve the desired result

Comment: Could you please share the table schema? Also, could you share what you tried?

Comment: You would need to use group by with a case statement. This is it in SQLServer. (rather than sqlite)
 `SELECT idField, SUM(CASE WHEN myBuySellfield = 'Sell' THEN valField ELSE 0 - valField END) FROM myTable GROUP BY idField`

Basically, Sum them together. but check whether its a buy (or sell) and inverse the value so its negative.

Comment: Please find the table structure below                                                                    ('CREATE TABLE results(\n        Symbol TEXT,\n        Trade_Exe_Date TEXT,\n        Trade_Type TEXT,\n        Action TEXT,\n        Price REAL,\n        Added_On TEXT\n        )',)